# AJAX request does not work (POST)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a little problem with a POST request using AJAX. The data just doesn't seem to get stored in the database. When I used GET instead of POST it worked, but the problem is that it sends a huge amount of data since it is imagedata from a canvas on the page. I tried to print out the size of the data that is sent to make sure it actually is correct before it is sent (it was about 10500 characthers long).

Here's the Javascript/AJAX-code:

```
if(type == "DrawingData" && Drawer)
{
    var CanvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
    var url = "DB_Com.php";
    var params = "DrawingData="+CanvasData;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

And here is the PHP-code:

```
if(isset($_POST['DrawingData']))
{
    $Image = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DrawingData']);

    $query = "UPDATE BlackboardDrawing SET Data = '$Image'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Any help is is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with "huge amount of data"? Don't tell me you fell for the "GET limit"…

Comment: Actually I think it's the PHP POST limit. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size. Check what the Ajax request returns with Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: @Shikiryu Got an GET limit error? Anyway to override it or change the size?

Comment: tried Content Type: multipart/formdata

Comment: Do you get any error messages from PHP?  You are displaying/logging messages, right?  also, you really want to ditch mysql_* because it's creaky, old, intended for MySQL 4 and is deprecated in all but name.

Comment: @talereader: Thanks for the tip, installed firebug. And it turned out that the server returned "HTTP Error 302 Moved temporarily" (but the page exists). So I removed .php from the URL since I have activated that the filename should be hidden, and now it works. But for the GET requests it works if I use .php after the filename.

Comment: So, the php code you displayed isn't actually what you are using? In other words, you are updating a row in the database, how does MySQL know which row you are updating?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax looks fine, but you need to POST the row id that you are updating. :

```
if(type == "DrawingData" && Drawer)
{
    var CanvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
    var url = "DB_Com.php";
    var rowid = 'your_row_id';
    var params = "DrawingData="+CanvasData+"rowid="+rowid;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

And change your PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['DrawingData']))
{
    $Image = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DrawingData']);
    $rowid = (int)$_POST['rowid'];
    $query = "UPDATE BlackboardDrawing SET Data = '$Image' WHERE id='$rowid'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```